# Rfacebook package. getPost and view

Tags: r, rfacebook

I am running the following code in R using `Rfacebook` package:

```
post <- getPost("155725841111588_10205062323825088", n=2000, token=my_oauth)
```

`View(post)` gave me the following error message:

> Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Can you assist on this?

Answer (score 0):

getPost() return a list not data frame.
view as `post$post`